# Why Sklearn PCA needs more samples than new features(n_components)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pca

When using Sklearn PCA algorithm like this

```
x_orig = np.random.choice([0,1],(4,25),replace = True)
pca = PCA(n_components=15)
pca.fit_transform(x_orig).shape
```

I get output

```
(4, 4)
```

I expected(want) it to be:

```
(4,15)
```

I get why its happening. In the documentation of sklearn ([here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)) it says(assuming their '==' is assignment operator):

```
n_components == min(n_samples, n_features)
```

But why are they doing this?
Also, how can I convert an input with shape [1,25] to [1,10] directly (without stacking dummy arrays)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each principal component is the projection of the data on an eigenvector of the data covariance matrix. If you have less samples *n* than features the covariance matrix has only *n* non-zero eigenvalues. Thus, there are only *n* eigenvectors/components that make sense.

In principle it could be possible to have more components than samples, but the superfluous components would be useless noise.

Scikit-learn raises an error instead of silently doing *something arbitrary*. This prevents users from shooting themselves in the foot. Having less samples than features can indicate a problem with the data, or a misconception about the methods involved.

Comment: So you are saying that if I stack dummy samples (>13) to original sample (of 1) to get component (say 14) then that will contain components with useless noise?

Comment: @lcukerd I meant to say that if the scikit-learn implementation accepted `n_components > n_samples` you would get useless noise (or maybe zeroed components).

Comment: If you "fake" additional data you may achieve the same effect. What exactly happens depends on what you use as dummy samples.

Comment: Has anyone had any experience with the pca module in matlab. I am converting matlab code into sklearn and having difficulty with the step. For example, I am running [EigenVectors,~,EigenValues] =  pca(X) where X is a double with dimensions 48x45. It returns a double for the eigenvectors coming back as 48x45 and eigen values with a length of 45. Any idea what matlab is doing?

Comment: @mhooper No idea. Better ask this as it's own [matlab]-tagged question to give it some visibility to Matlab experts.